# React Carousel with overflowing image

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel

Currently working on a react side project that has an api that returns an image array. Currently having issues with a third party Carousel, my image resizes to the screen but has overflow. I have tried

```
  height: auto;
  flex: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
```

Heres the React Component

```
`import React from 'react'
// import Carousel from '@brainhubeu/react-carousel'
// import '@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css'
import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel'

const headerImages = (props) => {
  const imageResults = props.trending.slice(0, 5).map(r => (
    <img key={r.id} src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280${r.backdrop_path}`} alt={r.title} className='header-image' />
  ))
  return <div className='header-images'>
    <Carousel>{imageResults}</Carousel>
  </div>
}

export default headerImages
```

`

The issue is the same with a different Carousel too.

Here is some screenshots: [image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]
[image: 3rd]
[image]

As you can see there's some white there (overflow) that is only present when I scroll down

Comment: could you add screenshot in question instead of link please , link seems blocked

Comment: I have edited the images

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz demo?

Comment: @invrt thats due to component overlaping , see this example and let me know if this is working https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick-carousel

Comment: @KOTIOS Issue is still there with the carousel you linked

Answer (score 0):

```
.App {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This solved the issue